# How do you set the range for ListPlot (mathematica)

Tags: graphing-functions, mathematica, data-analysis

I have a large set (about 2050 values) of data that I would like to make a graph out of. The data is in two columns in Excel. I copied the first column and made the list x={0, 3.6, 7.1, 10.7...} and with the second column i made y={0, 0, 0, ...} (there are non-zero values but they are much further along). Then I did s=Thread[{x,y}] . and then ListPlot[s]. The graph that comes out doesn' t make much sense to me (I have attached an image of the listplot and of the excel plot) The only thing that I can think of and see is that mathematica seems to be stopping the y values at 5 for some reason. However, I dont know how to extend the range for a listplot. 
Does anybody have any other ideas?
Thanks. 
 [image: Excel Image]

[image: Mathematica Image]

Comment: This should be moved to mathematica.stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have mixed the $x$ and $y$ values. Your thread command isn't working quite as you think. The 'easy' and naive way to do this is you can take the $x$ and $y$ values and create your points with

```
 points={}
 Do[AppendTo[points,{x[[i]],y[i]]}],{i,1,Length[x]}]
```

Assuming you have the same amount of $x$ and $y$ coordinates. Then you can just DiscretePlot the set points or however you wanted to plot it. Note also, it is unnecessary that you copied and pasted the points. Mathematica can import them as points directly. See the help menu for help on that!

Comment: I dont believe the x an y are switched, (if you look at the excel graph the x value should go up to about 7000 which it does, so i think they are in the right order. I'm all little confused about what you are doing with the AppendTo command. wont that simply make a list of points {x_i,Y_i}? which is what the thread command should do i believe. I did check the thread command and had it actually list out the values and it looks correct to me, it gives a list of all the x an y values paired up into coordinates so i dont believe that should be an issue.

Comment: @user11059 Without the code you used, I can't say. The plotting functions only plot the points you give them so the error cannot be there. So I can only assume you applied the Thread command incorrectly. It would be tricky to use Thread to make the points you want. Yes, my AppendTo command above creates all the points $(x,y)$. Since you have 2000 points, I doubt you checked them all. So unless you provide your coding in the question, I can only assume you created the points incorrectly.